# Icon is not changing

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to change an icon when a specific radio-button is selected.

However, the switch statement in the .dart code never changes the icon even though the switch is triggered.

Thanks for any help.

### .dart

```
class Gender extends Object with Observable {
    @observable
  String sex = '';

}

@observable String ikon = 'alarm';

  void onChangeRadioGroupHandler(dom.CustomEvent e) {
    gender.sex = (e.target as PaperRadioButton).label;

    switch(gender.sex)
    {
      case 'Male':
        ikon = 'done';
        break;

      case 'Female':
        ikon = 'cached';
        break;
  }
```

### .html

```
<div layout vertical center>
    <div layout horizontal self-center>
      <paper-icon-button icon='{{ikon}}' on-click='{{toggle}}'></paper-icon-button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <core-collapse id='core--collapse'>
    <div layout vertical'>
      <label id='genderLbl'></label>
      <paper-radio-group id='gender-group' on-change='{{onChangeRadioGroupHandler}}'>
        <paper-radio-button name='Male' label='Male'></paper-radio-button><br>
        <paper-radio-button name='Female' label='Female'></paper-radio-button>
      </paper-radio-group>
    </div>
  </core-collapse>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you write `done` or `cached` directly into the HTML instea of `{{ikon}}`?

Comment: It does not update that way either - I did that by adding an id to the paper-icon-button and worked with the retrieved button. Even with casting the returned object to PaperIconButton does not work.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. It doesn't seem to answer my question. I'd like to know if the icons work "hardcoded" without any code.

Comment: Sorry. The icons are displayed hard-coded. In the above example, for instance |@observable String ikon = 'alarm';| statement does display the icon. It is the switch statement that does not update the icon as expected.